# Errors when trying to install R packages from source (tidyverse)

Tags: r, tidyverse, rtools

I was trying to install tidyverse in R. Some packages gave me error messages so I tried to google and resolve them. I found some solutions but ran into new errors and now I'm stuck and can't seem to make progress. The three main errors left are:

1.

> WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently
> installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of
> Rtools before proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/

> *** arch - i386 c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c capture.c -o capture.o sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory make: ***
> [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: capture.o] Error 127
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'

A few packages used old binary files so I tried installing RTools40 (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) to force installation from source files. I followed the instructions on the website and everything seems to work until I run this code:

```
install.packages("tidyverse", type = "source")
```

This gives me the error message above (and more, I have posted the whole message from the console down below). "c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc" that path and file definitely exists, I checked. It still says I haven't installed Rtools... What am I missing?

2.

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =
> vI[[i]]) :  namespace 'dplyr' 0.8.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is
> required ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'

This happens with some packages and I assume it should be fixed if point 1 is fixed.

Full message from install tidyverse:

> install.packages("tidyverse", type = "source") WARNING: Rtools is
> required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please
> download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before
> proceeding:
>
> https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/ Installing package into
> ‘C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> also installing the dependencies ‘rlang’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘vctrs’,
> ‘dplyr’, ‘broom’, ‘dbplyr’, ‘modelr’
>
> versuche URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 915685 bytes (894 KB) downloaded 894
> KB
>
> versuche URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyselect_1.1.0.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 90842 bytes (88 KB) downloaded 88 KB
>
> versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/vctrs_0.3.6.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 778016 bytes (759 KB)
> downloaded 759 KB
>
> versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dplyr_1.0.2.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 935654 bytes (913 KB)
> downloaded 913 KB
>
> versuche URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.7.3.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 618499 bytes (604 KB)
> downloaded 604 KB
>
> versuche URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/dbplyr_2.0.0.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 534910 bytes (522 KB) downloaded 522
> KB
>
> versuche URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/modelr_0.1.8.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 121333 bytes (118 KB) downloaded 118
> KB
>
> versuche URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tidyverse_1.3.0.tar.gz' Content
> type 'application/x-gzip' length 712837 bytes (696 KB) downloaded 696
> KB
>
> - installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
>   ** Paket 'rlang' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
>   ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386 c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG -I./lib/         -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c capture.c -o capture.o sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory make: ***
> [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: capture.o] Error 127
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rlang'
>
> - removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rlang'
> - restoring previous 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/rlang' In R CMD INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation of
>   package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
> - installing *source* package 'vctrs' ...
>   ** Paket 'vctrs' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
>   ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386 c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG          -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c altrep-rle.c -o altrep-rle.o sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc: No such file or directory make: ***
> [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:208: altrep-rle.o] Error 127
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'vctrs'
>
> - removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/vctrs'
> - restoring previous 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/vctrs' In R CMD INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation of
>   package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
> - installing *source* package 'tidyselect' ...
>   ** Paket 'tidyselect' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
>   namespace 'rlang' 0.4.5 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.6 is required
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'tidyselect'
> - removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyselect'
> - restoring previous 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyselect' In R CMD
>   INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status
> - installing *source* package 'dplyr' ...
>   ** Paket 'dplyr' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
>   ** libs
>
> *** arch - i386 c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG          -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c filter.cpp -o filter.o sh: c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++: No such file or directory make: ***
> [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:215: filter.o] Error 127
> ERROR: compilation failed for package 'dplyr'
>
> - removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dplyr'
> - restoring previous 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dplyr' In R CMD INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation of
>   package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status
> - installing *source* package 'broom' ...
>   ** Paket 'broom' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
>   namespace 'dplyr' 0.8.5 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'
> - removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/broom' In R CMD INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
> - installing *source* package 'dbplyr' ...
>   ** Paket 'dbplyr' erfolgreich entpackt und MD5 Summen überprüft
>   ** R
>   ** inst
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading Error : object 'relocate' is not exported by 'namespace:dplyr' ERROR: lazy loading
>   failed for package 'dbplyr'
> - removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/dbplyr' In R CMD INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependency 'broom' is not
>   available for package 'modelr'
> - removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/modelr' In R CMD INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘modelr’ had non-zero exit status ERROR: dependencies 'broom',
>   'dbplyr', 'modelr' are not available for package 'tidyverse'
> - removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/tidyverse' In R CMD INSTALL Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: did you ever resolve this? experiencing a similar error myself.

Comment: Eh, I can't quite remember if this was the solution to this problem but I needed to update R (not RStudio) manually and was then able to update RStudio further, which enabled to install tidyverse (or another package...).

Comment: yup! Turns out my Rtools and R versions didn't match. Thanks for the follow up!